Convert R8 texture to R32F
I have a single channel 2D image (for instance, R8). I would like to use this data as a texture. However, the texture internal format should be R32F since I need accurate linear sampling in my shader. I know that I can easily convert data type on CPU and then upload the R32F data.
Is there an alternative way?

It may be cheaper to keep your texture in its current format, and apply the bilinear filtering in your shader code. Each fragment would need to read 4 bytes either way, but in R8 format more of the texture fits in cache, so you'll quite likely see better performance that way.

I recommend using OpenCV.

You can of course draw a quad to an R32F Render Target, sampling your R8 to blit it GPU side without going via CPU conversion. I don't have a code sample to share but I'll leave that as low hanging fruit for an answer.
